# RSelenium: Uncollapse a Panel

Tags: rselenium

I am attempting to use RSelenium to check a box that is hidden from view due to the collapse panel.

```
    <div data-ddm-collapsible-panel="Additional details" class="dfa-collapsiblepanel">
      <fieldset role="region" aria-labelledby="panel1">
        <legend id="panel1" role="heading">
          <span>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="ddm-icon ddm-icon-collapsed"></span>
              Additional details
            </a>
          </span>
        </legend>  
      </fieldset>
    </div>
```

I have tried a few different options but ran into the error of either the element not being found, or not visible. Some of my attempts:

```
    expand_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'class name', "dfa-collapsiblepanel")
```

Result: Unable to locate element

```
    expand_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', "panel1")
```

Result: Unable to locate element

I'm not familiar at all with xpath, but i attempted to modify the code found from searching  online and got this:

```
   expand_button<- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//div[contains(@data-ddm-collapsible-panel, 'Additional')]")
```

Error: No such element.

Comment: Can you give the website this issue relates to?

Comment: it requires a secured login for this.but it is on google's doubleclick product